# Encrypt File Using Crypto JS in Aura Component

Tags: crypto, js

We want to encrypt the input file on client side using javascript in our aura component.

We are trying to use CryptoJS(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js).

We have added this JS library as static resource and added in lightning component.

This library is working fine in Visualforce page. But in aura lightning component, we are getting error says "CryptoJS is not defined" when we call below method.

CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('123', '1234567887654321');

Same method is working fine in the VF page. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the file 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js' instead of only aes.js file. May be aes.js internally dowloads all dependencies when you are using inside VF Page and that's how it is working inside VF Page.

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi both,I am also stuck with same issue like "AES is not defined" . Do we need to load both JS files in LWC ? whats the approach you used. Can you please share the code snippet here.

Comment: You can try browserify module to create a single js to use inside LWC Component.